# Let $A_{3×3}$ be a non zero matrix with property $A^3 = 0$. Then Number of linearly independent eigen vectors of $A$ is 1. 0 2. 1 3. 2 4. 3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A_{3×3}$ be a non-zero matrix with the property $A^3 = 0$. Then, the number of linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$ is
>
> 1. $0$
> 2. $1$
> 3. $2$
> 4. $3$

---

My Attempt:

We know that for a given matrix $A$ if $\exists X \neq 0$ such that $AX = \lambda X$ then $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $A$ and $X$ is an eigen vector of $A$. So option 1 never possible. Also $A^3 = 0$ implies $A$ is nilpotent. We know that eigen values of nilpotent matrix are zero. I have no knowledge how to prove that one option in the given options is true and rest are false. Please help me.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ has families of up to $7$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Woops. deleted

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, the question is ill-posed. For $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 &0\\0 & 0 &1\\ 0& 0 &0\end{bmatrix}$, there is only one linearly independent vector. But for $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 &0\\0 & 0 &0\\ 0& 0 &0\end{bmatrix}$ there are two linearly independent vectors. It is easy to show, that $\lambda=0$ is the only eigenvalue of a nilpotent matrix, since $0=A^3v=\lambda^3 v$ for all eigenvectors $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Since $3$ is odd, there has to be an (at least one dimensional) eigenspace.

Since $A\neq 0$, there are at most 2 linearly independent eigenvectors.

But the generalized eigenspace (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Overview_and_definition) is three-dimensional ($\mathbb R^3$).

Comment: That's assuming the space is $\mathbb{R}^3$, which wasn't given,  If it's a bigger space, it could have more eigenvectors

Comment: Hello :) Ah ok, i didn't know. What does $A_{3\times 3}$ mean? I really don't know.

Comment: Oh, never mind. That part was added since I first looked at the question (The subscript), and I didn't look again before commenting